# Getting "The Declaration Isn't Referenced" error in Flutter even though it is referenced in main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am completing the Angela Yu Flutter course, am working on the "Quizzler" project, and continue to get an error stating that the declaration in a dart file isn't referenced, however it appears (to me) to be. Both getQuestionText and getQuestionAnswer are resulting in the same error. I have made sure to import quiz_brain.dart into main.dart. Any help would be very much appreciated.

excerpt from quiz_brain.dart:

```
  void nextQuestion (){
    if (_questionNumber < _questionBank.length){_questionNumber++;
  }

  String get() {
    return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionText;
  }

    String getQuestionText (){
      return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionText;
  }
  bool getQuestionAnswer () {
    return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionAnswer;
  }
}
```

excerpt from main.dart:

```
Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                quizBrain.getQuestionText(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the quiz_brain.dart excerpt that you provided, please make sure you have your curly braces correct. You missed the curly closing braces for your `nextQuestion()` function. Because of that misplacement of that curly closing braces from the `nextQuestion()` function, you had an extra curly closing brace at the bottom of your excerpt.

Corrected quiz_brain.dart

```
void nextQuestion (){
  if (_questionNumber < _questionBank.length){
    _questionNumber++;
  }
}

String get() {
  return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionText;
}

String getQuestionText () {
    return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionText;
}

bool getQuestionAnswer () {
  return _questionBank[_questionNumber].questionAnswer;
}
```

Secondly, your `get()` function and `getQuestionText()` function does exactly the same thing, you may want to removing one of it.

Comment: Thank you!!! I stared at that function for an hour and didn't pick up on that! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: That is awesome to hear Chris!
If my answer solved your problem, can you please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer? That would greatly help other searchers with a question similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if quizBrain has been initialized in main.dart? Make sure that quizBrain also has access to List _questionBank

Answer (score 0):

It appears when your function is not returning the correct type of data that is mentioned in the signature.

Try checking all the control branches in your function body that the return statement is properly placed.